# Vim-Adventure at level 12

Tags: vim-adventures

I'm trying to finish the level 12 in Vim-Adventures, but it is a little bit hard so far.

[image]

I tried to insert text (purple text) with `i`, `a` and `o`, but it didn't work. I wanted to paste the text, but I didn't find the words to complete that.

[image]

Could anyone be able to help me at this point?

Comment: What exactly are you struggling with?  Pasting text you've yanked?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to just paste the text, because it needs its own line, and I'm not sure how you would get a newline into a named register (and I think the game author wants you to practice using **o** and **O**).

1. In your picture, if you stand on the `d` in `dolphins` and press **o**, it will start a new line where you type "believed that they were`Esc`".
2. Next, stand on the `m` in `man`, last line of the text, and press **o**.  It will create a new line where you type "same reasons.`Esc`"

*If it doesn't work the first time,* try again in some slightly different way (navigate to `man` using **G** instead of **j**, or standing on a different tile before you press **o**, etc.) because I had trouble the first time -- I thought it should have worked, but it gave a message about not overflowing the text boundaries or something.  It worked the second time -- and I don't recall exactly what I did differently.